# $\Sigma\le S_{p-1}$ abelian subgroup of order $p-1$, such that $\sigma(i)\equiv\sigma(1)i\pmod p$. Then $\Sigma$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

**Claim**. For $p$ a prime, let $\Sigma\le S_{p-1}$ be a abelian subgroup of order $p-1$, such that, for every $\sigma\in\Sigma$ and $i\in\{1,\dots,p-1\}$:
$$\sigma(i)\equiv\sigma(1)i\pmod p \tag1$$
Then $\Sigma$ is cyclic. $\space\Box$

For example, for $p=5$, the only $\Sigma$ complying with $(1)$ is $\Sigma=\langle (1243)\rangle$. For $p=7$ and $p=11$ there's nothing to prove, provided that one knows that the only abelian groups of order $6$ and $10$ are cyclic. Going up, the first nontrivial (to me) cases are then $p=13$ and $p=17$.

Is there any permutational proof of this claim? I've been trying to contradict $(1)$ by assuming that there is a subgroup $H\le \Sigma$ isomorphic to $C_q\times C_q$, where $q$ is a prime. I can do that, but not by bare permutation arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any group.  Let $G$ be a finite group and $\Pi(G)$ the group of permutations of elements of $G$.  Then you have an injective homomorphism $G\mapsto \Pi(G)$ induced by left multiplication.
$$\sigma_g(h) = gh$$
and since $\sigma_g(1) = g$ you can write this as
$$\sigma_g(h) = \sigma_g(1) h$$
The identity $\sigma_g(1)=g$ also shows that the image of $G$ acts transitively.

Comment: Note sure I can follow. None of the embeddings of Klein four-group into $S_4$ fulfils $(1)$.

Comment: @orione:  Each group uses its own multiplication, not $(1)$.  You can embed any group into the group of permutations of its elements via its multiplication.  There's no reason to expect to prove specific properties of a group (such as being abelian or cyclic) using a construction of a faithful permutation representation usable on any group whatsoever.

Comment: But $(1)$ is what I want my particular permutation group $\Sigma$ to comply with, @JohnDoe.